# What does it mean for a probability generating function to be an exponential function

Tags: probability, exponential-function, generating-functions

If the probability-generating function $G_{S_{i}}(u+v)$ satisfies the functional equation
$$\begin{align*}
G_{S_{i}}(u+v) & =G_{S_{i}}(u) G_{S_{i}}(v)
\end{align*}$$
and exhibits the characteristics of an exponential function, where a function $f(x)$ satisfying $f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)$ can be represented as $f(x)=e^{kx}$, can I infer that the random variable $S_i$ follows a Poisson distribution? If so, could you please provide a proof for this claim?

Comment: Just exapand $e^{kx}$ in a power series.

Comment: It depends of what you call generating function of a random variable $X$. Either  it can be the generating function of moments $f(s)=E(e^{sX})$ and $f(s)=e^{ks}$ means $\Pr(X=k)=1;$ or if $X$ is valued on non negative integers and  it can be $f(s)=E(s^X).$ But $f(s)=e^{ks}$ is impossible if $k\neq 0$ since $f(1)$ must be $1.$